# Stop drag w/ click instead of release

Tags: macos, trackpad, ui

I'm currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 on a mid-2015 MacBook Pro.  I have tap to click enabled and have enabled dragging without drag lock.  Currently I am able to double-tap to start dragging, and then the drag stops when I raise my finger.  I want to be able to also end the drag by clicking, so the full sequence would look like tap-tap-drag-click instead of tap-tap-drag-release.  I can do this on my 2011 Macbook Air, also running Yosemite.  It feels really unnatural to me to have the drag continue after clicking down, and I keep intending to end the drag this way habitually.  Do I need to break my habit or is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Open Preferences => Accessibility.

Select Mouse & Trackpad

Click on **Trackpad Options...**

and under the Enable dragging option, which should be checked you should be showing **with drag lock**.

Select a different mode:

[image: Enable dragging options]

Perhaps you'll be comfortable with one of the other two modes.

Comment: I tried all of these modes.  None of them have the feature I'm looking for, which is present in the 2011 macbook air.

Comment: Dragging with drag lock works as you describe on my Trackpad on a late 2008 aluminum Macbook (either tap-tap-drag-tap or tap-tap-drag-click).  I did have a heck of a time getting the tap-tap interval right (click and drag works in any mode).  I find three finger drag unambiguous.  It can also be enabled in the Trackpad Preferences Point & Click tab.